# Android 2.2 SDK - Android Camera app missing import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I pulled down the latest source from GIT for the camera app, but android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo seems to be missing when it's imported (and messing the rest of the app up).  I tried changing from Android 2.2 to Google APIs 2.2, but that didn't do anything.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html), this is available since API level 9, i.e. Android 2.3.

Comment: Hmmm..I see that, but it's also used here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html. This is different from the 2.2 API example I think, so it must be a 2.3 example?